# git- strange characters in output (msys-git)

Tags: git, msysgit

I'm using msys-git and notice I often get strange characters in the output after doing a git pull.  I presume these are some sort of control characters that some terminals might understand but in a standard windows command prompt they result in this:

```
 Source/MidiLib/AudioChannelMixer.cpp      ←[m |    6 ←[32m+←[m
 Source/MidiLib/AudioEnvironment.cpp       ←[m |    4 ←[32m+←[m
 Source/MidiLib/EventIDs.h                 ←[m |    1 ←[32m+←[m
 Source/MidiLib/MidiAssignable.cpp         ←[m |  207 ←[32m+++++++++++++++++++++++++←[m←[31m---←[m
 Source/MidiLib/MidiAssignable.h           ←[m |   39 ←[32m+++++←[m←[31m-←[m
 Source/MidiLib/MidiAssignmentsDlg.cpp     ←[m |  101 ←[32m++++++++++++←[m←[31m--←[m
```

It's not really a problem, but annoying... is there a way to disable these characters and get a clean output?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

`git config --global color.ui false` should do it as those characters are responsible for changing the text color (which is not supported by the Windows console).

Comment: Yep that certainly helps though strangely I now get colors in the output!  The + are in normal color while the - are in red.  Fair enough... it just raises the question of what the +/- characters actually mean?

Comment: A “+” stands for an inserted line, a “-” stands for a removed line.