# Troubles with Artisan Tinker encoding

Tags: laravel, encoding, git-bash, laravel-artisan

I have got some trouble, that when I run artisan command, all special characters like spaces and braces get encoded in some weird way (I will post here as soon as I get to my home machine, but it looks like [m39[[ instead of space and others also like this).

That only occures on my home machine using Git Bash (latest 2.7.2 from git-scm). When I am using windows CMD or using Git Bash on other machines - everything is ok.

Update: 
here is an example :

```
†ђ[30;43mPHP error:  Undefined variable: a on line 1в†ђ[39;49m
```

Comment: I had this issue & it's something to do with bash being unable to interpret colour properly, or something along those lines. I tried lots of different things and not sure which one did the trick but there's quite a few questions here on SO on the same issue, here's a few for you to check out: 1. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1077382/git-strange-characters-in-output-msys-git 2. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33537366/artisan-showing-inserting-32m-344m-and-similar 3. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5921556/in-git-bash-on-windows-7-colors-display-as-code-when-running-cucumber-or-rspec

Comment: @haakym could you post that comment as an answer so I can apply the bounty to you? the last answer from the third link helped me

Comment: Glad you got it working! Not going to say no to that after spending 250 bounty the other day and not accepting any answer lol.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had this issue and it's something to do with git bash being unable to interpret colour properly, or something along those lines.

I tried lots of different things and not sure which one did the trick but there's quite a few questions here on SO on the same issue, here's a few for you to check out:

1. [git- strange characters in output (msys-git)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1077382/git-strange-characters-in-output-msys-git)
2. [Artisan showing inserting "32m", "34;4m" and similar](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33537366/artisan-showing-inserting-32m-344m-and-similar)
3. [In Git Bash on Windows 7, Colors display as code when running Cucumber or rspec](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5921556/in-git-bash-on-windows-7-colors-display-as-code-when-running-cucumber-or-rspec)

Comment: need to wait 18 hours